# Watir-webdriver: Locating the last ul element on page

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

Lets say ive got several( I dont know how many ) `ul` elements, Unfortunately they all have the same class, and their ids are generated randomly.
All i know is that the one i want is the last one.

Is there a way to easily locate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a collection of the ul elements (using `uls`) and then take the last one (using `last`).

For example, given the page:

```
<html>
  <ul><li>1</li></ul>
  <ul><li>2</li></ul>
  <ul><li>3</li></ul>
</html>
```

Then you can get the collection (ie all) ul elements with:

```
browser.uls
```

The ul collection includes a [`last`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/ElementCollection#last-instance_method) method to get the last element:

```
browser.uls.last
#=> #<Watir::UList:0x4e3c436a located=false selector={:element=>(webdriver element)}>

browser.uls.last.text
#=> "3"
```